# Nested loops across to worksheets not working

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive me if this is a dumb question - I haven't tried programming for about 20 years so I'm rather rusty.

Given the following code:

```
Count = 0
Count2 = 0
Set BlankCell = Sheets("Credits").Range("L13")
Set SpareCell = Sheets("Telesales").Range("N1")

   For Count = 0 To EndOfCredits
      For Count2 = 0 To EndOfMerge
         If BlankCell.Offset(Count) = SpareCell.Offset(Count2) Then
         BlankCell.Offset(Count, 1) = SpareCell.Offset(Count2, -1)
         End If
      Next Count2
  Next Count
```

This is supposed to compare 2 lists against each other. If there's a match,  the value to the cell to the left of SpareCell is supposed to appear in the cell to the right of BlankCell.

It doesn't. It's been three days. I'm beginning to lose the will to live

Comment: can explain the `It doesn't.` ? What is happening and what is supposed to happen? maybe give an example

Comment: Thanks. Mine works properly if you spot that you reset EndOfCredits to 0 earlier in the program. Your answer made me go through the code line by line so thanks again. I'm just off to kick a cat.

Comment: well, I am glad youve sorted it out. If my answer has helped you please accept it :)

Comment: @mehow:  `blankCell.Offset(count, 0)` is the same as writing `BlankCell.Offset(Count)` For example `BlankCell.Offset(0,1)` is the same as writing `BlankCell.Offset(,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

count = 0
count2 = 0

Set blankCell = Sheets("Credits").Range("L13")
Set spareCell = Sheets("Telesales").Range("N1")

For count = 0 To endOfCredits
    For count2 = 0 To endOfMerge
        If blankCell.Offset(count, 0) = spareCell.Offset(count2, 0) Then
            blankCell.Offset(count, 1) = spareCell.Offset(count2, -1)
        End If
    Next count2
Next count

End Sub
```

My full working version with sample data as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Dim count As Long
Dim count2 As Long
Dim endOfCredits As Long
Dim endOfMerge As Long

Dim blankCell As Range
Dim spareCell As Range

count = 0
count2 = 0
Set blankCell = Sheets("Credits").Range("L13")
Set spareCell = Sheets("Telesales").Range("N1")

endOfCredits = 17
endOfMerge = 10

For count = 0 To endOfCredits
    For count2 = 0 To endOfMerge
        If blankCell.Offset(count, 0) = spareCell.Offset(count2, 0) Then
            blankCell.Offset(count, 1) = spareCell.Offset(count2, -1)
        End If
    Next count2
Next count

End Sub
```

data before

sheet **Credits**

[image]

sheet **Telesales**

[image]

data after ran macro

[image]